# Get rid of hornets: The nest has been removed, but the hornets keep rebuilding

Tags: pest-control

I have what I *think* is a **hornets' nest** on the soffit of my house (I'm not sure exactly what kind of bee or insect it is).

[image]

**The nest has been removed** since the photo was taken, however, **the hornets keep rebuilding**. They seem to build a new portion of nest about the size of a soda can each day. I remove the nest each day, but they are undeterred, and continue to rebuild.

Also, they have started to swarm the [sewer vent pipe](http://bestjobgoals.club/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/roof-vent-pipe-boot-roof-plumbing-vent-pipe-covers-the-best-of-with-ventilation-remodel.jpg) on the roof (not shown in photo). This is quite concerning; **I don't want these things in my house**. The pipe is about 2ft to the left of the nest, on the roof of the dormer.

Most people I've talked to recommend spraying the nest with hornet-specific insecticide. I can do this, but it's occurred to me that there isn't really much to spray.

**How can I get rid of the hornets?**

Comment: Get a brown paper bag, grey shopping bag filled with plush, or something similar and hang it nearby the nest. Hornets are highly territorial and if they 'think' another nest is nearby, they should vacate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had luck by spraying the nest with pesticide in the evening, when most should be at the nest rather than foraging, to maximize kill count and reduce danger to me because they are less active.

Then remove the nest and *spray the entire nest area with the ubiquitous spray lubricant that comes in a blue and yellow can with the number forty on it*. I do not know why this seems to deter them from rebuilding in the same spot, but have been told that it neutralizes the pheromone scent that attracts them to build in the same spot again. Try it on the vent pipe too.

Answer (score 1):

Try washing area with Javax, Mr Clean, or other harsh cleaning agent. Get rid of the pheromone smell