# Spray can pole extender

Tags: tools, pest-control, hand-tools, ladder, spraypainting

I have a [hornets' nest](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/145819/get-rid-of-hornets-the-nest-has-been-removed-but-the-hornets-keep-rebuilding) that I want to spray with insecticide.

[image] [image]

The hive is approximately 20-25ft from ground level.

---

The insecticide that I have is in a aerosol spray can with a large actuator.

While the product is marketed as having a range of 20ft, I have found this claim to be false. In reality it only has a range of 6ft.

---

I would prefer not to climb up to the area on a ladder, for fear of being in *swarming range* of the hornets.

Instead, I would like to build a pole-based contraption that would allow me trigger and spray the can from the end of a [10ft pole](https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/p.12-inch-emt-conduit.1000106377.html).

```
My height + arms length =  8ft
Pole                    = 10ft
Spray range             =  6ft

Sum                     = 24ft
```

---

**How can I make such a contraption?**

*Edit: I live in Canada, where specialty products like [this](https://www.amazon.ca/4most-Innovations-GSP0205-Sprayer-Extension/dp/B078WFJX9B/ref=sr_1_fkmr2_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1535251913&sr=8-1-fkmr2&keywords=pray%20Can%20Extension) take a long time to be delivered, and are hard to find locally.*

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0042T5PBO/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_6dHGBbBC4FQTC

Comment: @Tyson Good idea. [A bit pricey in Canada](https://www.amazon.ca/4most-Innovations-GSP0205-Sprayer-Extension/dp/B078WFJX9B/ref=sr_1_fkmr2_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1535251913&sr=8-1-fkmr2&keywords=pray+Can+Extension), and it would take a few days to get here, but it might be worth it.

Comment: Lowe’s has one too

Comment: The one at Lowe’s isn’t for a pole I see, but google “spray can pole adapter”. There are many.

Comment: I have done it from a ladder. Do it at night and do NOT be directly under the nest (drips and still live but injured wasps will drop). That type of nest seems like those of mud-dauber wasps, wicked multiple stings be careful. Have a least 2 cans to soak thoroughly.

Comment: For any poor Canadians that are in range of a Lee Valley, [this](http://www.leevalley.com/en/wood/page.aspx?p=68999&cat=2,51555&ap=1) might be an option.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image: Wordless Workshop]

That's from *Best of Wordless Workshop* by Ray Doty; the original was a monthly column in *Popular Science.* (Published sometime between 1971-1985)

The retail versions probably make more sense, but you can hum the theme from the A-Team while exterminating with this one. Besides, Wordless Workshop was a great feature.

Comment: I love it. Do you recommend [this book](https://www.amazon.ca/Wordless-Workshop-Easy-Make-Projects/dp/0312000618/ref=olp_product_details?_encoding=UTF8&me=)?

Comment: Looks like I had the title wrong, that cartoon is page 44 of the book you linked. The book is a great way to experience the column if you didn't get a change to read the magazine. Odds are good that if you love that one you'll like at least one of the other 119 in the book. (Wordless Workshop was always a single page comic solving some household dilemma.)

Comment: that's better than duct-taping to a stick and ON and hurrying...

Answer (score 2):

Why build one when someone already invented and built it for you? Check the ubiquitous on-line shopping site with the name that is also a river in S. America:

[image]

Comment: As mentioned to @Tyson: It's a good idea. [A bit pricey in Canada](https://www.amazon.ca/4most-Innovations-GSP0205-Sprayer-Extension/dp/B078WFJX9B/ref=sr_1_fkmr2_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1535251913&sr=8-1-fkmr2&keywords=pray+Can+Extension), and it would take a few days to get here, but it might be worth it.

Comment: I wonder if I could adapt my [pole pruner](https://www.amazon.ca/4most-Innovations-GSP0205-Sprayer-Extension/dp/B078WFJX9B/ref=sr_1_fkmr2_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1535251913&sr=8-1-fkmr2&keywords=pray+Can+Extension) for this purpose?

Comment: Yup, rig a wood lever from the pruning blade to push the button? I dunno but it might be a hoot to try. Who says "be a hoot", am I turning into my dad?